# Fourier transform spherically symmetric function with complex constant

Tags: complex-analysis, integral-transforms, fourier-transform

In Gradshteyn's section 17.24 on Fourier transform pairs for spherically symmetric functions, the third entry relates

$\frac{e^{-ar}}{r}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{(a^2 + k^2)^2}$.

I think that there is a mistake on the right hand side, which should be $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{a^2 + k^2}$.

My question is if this relation still holds if $a$ is a complex constant.

Comment: I guess you are right, by checking the special case at $k=0$.

Answer (score 0):

(1). Yes. There is a mistake on Gradshteyn's book, section 17.24 on p 1120, in the book "Table of integrals, series, and products" 7th. Ed. The right one should be that you pointed out.
(2). Cf. [this problem's excellent anser](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3127211/587075) by J.G.
Following J.G.'s work,
$\tilde{f}(k)=2\pi\int_0^{\pi}{d\theta[\sin{\theta}\int
_0^{\infty}{re^{-ar-ikr\cos{\theta}}dr}]}=2\pi\int_0^{\pi}{d\theta[\sin{\theta}\int
_0^{\infty}{re^{r\cdot(-a-ik\cos{\theta})}dr}]}\\=2\pi\int_0^{\pi}{d\theta\{\sin{\theta}[\frac{1}{-a-ik\cos{\theta}}\int
_0^{\infty}{rde^{r\cdot(-a-ik\cos{\theta})}]}\}}\\=2\pi\int_0^{\pi}{d\theta\{\sin{\theta}\frac{1}{-a-ik\cos{\theta}}[re^{r\cdot(-a-ik\cos{\theta})}|_{r=0}^{\infty}-\int
_0^{\infty}{e^{r\cdot(-a-ik\cos{\theta})}dr}]\}}$

,
it is clear that if $a$ is a complex number, to make the integral meaningful, the real part of $a$ should be positive!