# Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{r} e^{-\alpha r}$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I'm having some trouble finding the Fourier transform of 
$$ f(\mathbf{r}) = \dfrac{1}{r} e^{-\alpha r} $$
where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ and $\alpha$ is a nonzero integer. The problem gives the hint that you should take $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, but I can't seem to figure out how this helps the integration.

I'm just looking for a hint on how to proceed with this.

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Just to clarify, I'm trying to solve this integral:
$$ \tilde{f}(\mathbf{k}) = \int f(\mathbf{r})e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}} d^3 r$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, $\mathbf{r}$ is the vector $\vec{r}$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, the exponential vector was a typo, my bad.

Comment: @Kosta Division by a vector?

Comment: The vectors are fixed. They were typos.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702252/solution-of-the-yukawa-potential-fourier-representation-integral and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/fourier-transform-of-the-coulomb-potential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is $$\tilde{f}(k)=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi d\theta\left[\sin\theta\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{r}\exp -\alpha r\cdot \exp -ikr\cos\theta\cdot r^2 dr\right]\\=2\pi\int_0^\pi d\theta\frac{\sin\theta}{(\alpha+ik\cos\theta)^2}=\frac{2\pi}{ik}\left[\frac{1}{\alpha+ik\cos\theta}\right]_0^\pi=\frac{4\pi}{\alpha^2+k^2}.$$As a sanity check, you can verify $\int_0^\infty |\tilde{f}(k)|^2 k^2 dk=(2\pi)^3\int_0^\infty |f(r)|^2 r^2 dr=\frac{4\pi^3}{\alpha}$.

Comment: I think that this answer is erronous, cf. section 17.24 on p 1120, in the book "Table of integrals, series, and products" 7th. Ed. .  Your derivation did not consider the singular point on r = 0 where the residue theorem may be applied.

Comment: @wy_oou Gradshteyn and Ryzhik have a misprint, as can be inferred by e.g. dimensional analysis. Since $d^3\vec{r}=r^2drd\Omega$, there's no need for extra care at $r=0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I check the special value of k = 0, your answer is right and the book I refered to is wrong.